# SVG image does not resize on iOS8

Tags: html, css, svg

I have SVG picture with PNG fallback:

```
 <svg width=64 height=64>
  <image xlink:href="gender-male.svg"
   src="gender-male.png" width="100%" height="100%"> </image>
 </svg>
```

When I set different size via CSS for the outer SVG, it resizes the inner image correctly on all browsers:

```
 svg.small {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
 }
```

But on iOS8, the inner image does not scale and remains in original size:

[image: SVG on iOS8]

Demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/dhryv46y/)

I've tried various changes in SVG header:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="283px" height="283px" 
     viewBox="0 0 283.5 283.5" 
     enable-background="new 0 0 283.5 283.5" xml:space="preserve">
```

The other image:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet"
     x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 283.5 283.5" 
     enable-background="new 0 0 283.5 283.5" xml:space="preserve">
```

And also various CSS methods ([max-width](https://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/dhryv46y/4/), [absolute position](https://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/dhryv46y/8/), etc.) for the image but nothing seems to work. Even [setting the size in JS](https://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/dhryv46y/7/) does not work.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Not a solution, obviously, but is there any particular reason why you don't use quotes on the attributes of the outer svg element?

Comment: @BramVanroy I'm just being lazy. _The quotes are optional in HTML so it does not break anything and also saves few bytes ("64px" = 6 bytes; 64 = 2 bytes)._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/dhryv46y/10/) is actually pretty easy, but you must know what is the problem.

The problem is, that the outer `SVG` element is resized based on its CSS properties, but the inner `IMAGE` is rendered based on the HTML properties `width` and `height`.

To make it render correctly, you simply need to change HTML size attributes every time the actual size of the element changes:

```
    if ((-1 < navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone')
      || -1 < navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad'))
      && window.navigator.userAgent.match(new RegExp('OS ([1-8])_'))) {
     //iOS8 and older cannot correctly resize SVG graphic inside element resized by CSS

        $(window).on('resize.svg-size', function() {
            $('svg').each(function() {
                var me = $(this);

                //if height is set to auto, you may need to fix it first
                me.css('height', me.width() * me.data('ratio'));

                //set HTML attributes to current size defined in CSS
                me.attr('width', me.width());
                me.attr('height', me.height());

                //if there is also another container, fix it as well
                me.parent().height(me.parent().width() * me.data('ratio'));
            });
        });
        //call the handler when the page is loaded
        $(function() { $(window).triggerHandler('resize.svg-size'); });
    } //Fix for gender select size on iOS8 and older
```

HTML (outer `DIV` is optional):

```
<div class="image-container">    
  <svg width=64 height=64 data-ratio=1><!-- square image -->
      <image xlink:href="gender-male.svg"
             src="gender-male.png" width="100%" height="100%"> </image>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="image-container">    
  <svg width=100 height=75 data-ratio="0.75"><!-- 4:3 image -->
      <image xlink:href="gender-female.svg"
             src="gender-female.png" width="100%" height="100%"> </image>
  </svg>
</div>
```